# Questions whose answer was posed in the question body, or in the comments below, what should one do?

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions, best-practices

In the effort to "clean" the unanswered questions (credits to all of you), one bumps into questions already answered by the querist, either within the question body, or in the comments below. Some examples are:

- [Samsung Galaxy S3 direct call always calls the same number](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24886/16265)
- [HTC Sense Keeps Crashing Even After Factory Reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/6763/16265)

### What would be the appropriated action to take?

**Suggestion:**

If the question is useful and should be preserved, answer it as a community wiki, and clean up the question body *(if applied)*.

Comment: Related: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/a/282/440

Comment: @Flow Wasn't sure about the "unanswered-questions" tag due to the fact that technically they have an answer! While not on the designated spot :) Tks.

Comment: @Flow I've read the "related" just now. While answers there are what we are trying to determine! The question itself has a misleading title.. (one would assume that the querist provided the answer while posing the question, not after with an inappropriate method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the OP puts the answer in the body of the question, or if the answer ends up in the comments on the question, leave a comment asking the OP or the commenter to put the information in an actual answer.

If that doesn't happen within a couple of days, feel free to put the information in an answer yourself. To prevent the appearance of reputation point whoring/stealing, it'd be best to mark the answer as Community Wiki. This way, at least, people can vote on the answer and future readers can find the better solution.

See also:

- [Mark a comment as answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question)
- [flag a comment as "should be an answer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54762/flag-a-comment-as-should-be-an-answer)
- [Marking comment as an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77900/marking-comment-as-an-answer)
- [Best way to deal with questions answered by the OP in the question instead of in an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108969/best-way-to-deal-with-questions-answered-by-the-op-in-the-question-instead-of-in)

---

Of course, that all assumes the answer is worth keeping around. If the solution is something obvious/trivial like "I rebooted my phone" then the proper course of action is to close the question as "Too Localized".